# Configuration of multiple IoT devices in a local network

Tags: c#, networking, go, configuration

Imagine a room with 10+ Raspberry Pi's. All of them get conencted to the local network by ethernet and are then powered on. They are running an application which needs to be configured properly. Since the users are not technically gifted the configuration file is created by a user friendly program running on a Windows PC in the same network.

The application on the Pi is written in Go, the Windows program in C#.

What would be a good approach to retrieve the configuration from the windows machine? Since the devices don't know about other, I need to implement some kind of **device discovery** first.

Another approach I have seen was just blindly broadcasting the configuration via UDP but that really seems inappropriate.

Comment: [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/docs.md) may be helpful but is more likely overkill

Comment: Yeah etcd is awesome but would be an overkill imho. Another idea: I'm exposing an API endpoint and I could then post the configuration to it.